# Image Drag and Drop Debug

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am developing a web application where a user can drag and drop images from his local computer to get the average color of it. For some reason the drag and drop zone doesn't work. I know there is a problem with my addImage function, but I can't really figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
     <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Get Image Average Color</title>
    <link href="css/finalProject.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Average Color of an Image</h1>
    <p>Drop an image in the box below to get the average color of it in RGB values! </p>
    <div id="dropBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="drag(event)" > <p>Drop your image here! :)</p> </div>
    <div id="images"></div>
 <div class="colorBox"> </div>
 </body>
```

JS code:

```
      function addImage(file) {
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          var hue = document.querySelector(".colorBox");
          img.onload = function () {
              var rgb = averageColor(img); 
              var rgbString = "rgb(" + r + " , "+ g + ", " +  b + ")";
              rgbString.innerHTML="";
              hue.style.backgroundColor = rgbString;
          }
              document.getElementById('images').appendChild(hue);
      }

    /* draw the image in a canvas element then use the
    getImageData method to return an array containing RGBA values*/

   function averageColor(img) {
     //Create canvas and set width and height to that of the image
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var width = canvas.width = img.naturalWidth; 
            var height = canvas.height = img.naturalHeight;

            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
            var data = imageData.data;
            var r = 0; // Set rgb values to 0 for un-supported brows.
            var g = 0;
            var b = 0; 

        //loop over each pixel
         for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i += 4) {
            r += data[i];
            g += data[i+1];
            b += data[i+2];
          }

            //get the average values for rgb using Math.floor 

            r = Math.floor(r / (data.length / 4));
            g = Math.floor(g / (data.length / 4));
            b = Math.floor(b / (data.length / 4));

            return { r: r, g: g, b: b };
    }

    //create the drag and drop zone..



    function drag(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            //event.dataTransfer.setData;
            event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy"; //this property will copy the image to the new location
         }

    function drop(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            var img = event.dataTransfer.createObjectURL(file); 
            event.dropBox.appendChild(document.getElementById(img)); 
            //image into the drop zone
            document.getElementById("images").innerHTML = '';


        }
```

Comment: `For some reason the drag and drop zone doesn't work`  What do you mean it doesn't work?  Your drop method doesn't get called?

Comment: Can you put your code in jsfiddle.net please ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't get called. No change appear in the HTML page. Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reemdos/w35wsot5/  Thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing this exclusively on jsfiddle, you need to consider that the functions you write on the JavaScript box are not in the global context, but when you add your events in HTML like this: `<div id="dropBox" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="drag(event)">` it will only work if the functions are in the global context.

A workaround on jsfiddle is to write it like this:

```
window.drop = function(event){}
```

Instead of

```
function drop(event){}
```

If you are developing somewhere else, just make sure that the event handling functions are global and then you can write it in the more friendly second version.

As you have already acknowledged, there are a bunch of other problems in your code.  Here is [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w35wsot5/2/) with a quick pass on it fixing some of the other issues. With some minor changes your code works as expected and the box is filled with the average color.